# How was the first upvote / downvote given?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

[The current rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) say that the required number of reputation points to give upvote or downvote are 15 points and 125 points respectively. I'm wondering who gave the first upvote / downvote and how did they get the required rep. I suppose the site rules were more permissive back then?

Comment: Don't forget that accepting an answer doesn't require any reputation. Nor does suggesting an edit. The first accepted answer would have given someone enough reputation to upvote, and from there...

Comment: See [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237): *When everyone is at 1, where does the reputation start?*

Comment: @JonK However suggested edits require having users with 2k reputation to approve of the edits.

Comment: @Servy Very true, good point. Was the threshold originally lower when SO was brand new? I know some of the other SE sites have different thresholds for various moderation actions. But couldn't the original poster still approve the edit themselves? I thought they got a binding vote on suggested edits.

Comment: @JonK Pretty sure the feature was rolled out after the site had existed for some time.

Comment: Suggested edits by low-rep users is a relatively recent addition.

Comment: Of course I believe the "everyone at 1 rep" has been changed since the site launched so the answer here might not actually apply to "when" the first upvote downvote was cast on SO, since SO was the first SE site and all, I mean meta didn't exist back then

Comment: Clearly the guidelines were different when the original site was created, or it never would have come into existence. I'm not sure what the purpose of this question is other than to ask "what came first, the chicken or the egg?". What's the relevance of any answers other than historical trivia? It's clear that Jeff and Joel didn't decide to create a site that depends on up/down voting as a major part of its functionality and then not allow anyone to vote up or down during the site startup, and that guidelines evolved over time.

Comment: I propose to give the OP an [Archaeologist Badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/74/archaeologist), even if the requirements for the badge are somewhat different.

Comment: @Servy suggested edits didn't exist until years after the site launched. Users could edit their own posts (in most cases) and high-rep users could edit others' (I think it's always kicked in at 2000 rep, but don't recall).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Quoting from the [central FAQ on how reputation works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> #### When everyone is at 1, where does the reputation start?
>
> There are three ways a new Stack Exchange site can be bootstrapped:
>
> - Users come from another site in the network where they start with 100 reputation (if they have a linked account with 200+)
> - Users have their answers accepted or are the ones accepting answers from other users (+15 and +2 respectively)
> - Suggested edits are approved (the original poster has a binding vote on suggested edits if they are not yet approved or rejected)

All it takes is an accepted answer to reach 15 points. From there on out someone can vote and the whole system is bootstrapped.

This is quite apart from the fact that nowadays [private betas have far lower privilege requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared); everyone gets to vote at 1 rep, up *and* down.

Comment: Also worth noting that during the first week or two, lots of privileges are fixed at 1 - including up and down voting. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared

Comment: @Shog9 Out of interest, which ones aren't? Or does it vary site-to-site?

Comment: See the link, @JonK. Also note that this *doesn't apply to Stack Overflow*, since half these privileges didn't exist during the first few weeks of SO's beta and the privilege system was different anyway. I wasn't around for the first week or so, but I'm pretty sure there were at least a few days where the rep requirement for voting didn't exist - the first upvote from a non-dev account was cast prior to the user involved receiving any votes (including "Accept" votes).

Comment: What if that one someone is a total jerk and down-votes everyone?  He'd be quite lonely I suppose. :)

Comment: While reading your answer, i felt like how humans evolved?

Comment: @Richard: then the *next* person to have an answer accepted bootstraps the system.

Answer (score 19):

You can accept an answer without having any reputation and generate reputation.

Comment: Oh, the wonders of *Fiat Money*... So, each one of us is a mini-Federal Reserve? Cool!

Comment: @brasofilo now that you mention it, most of the site is that way. Specifically, few things *cost* rep, even if they *require* rep. I'm noticing a different socioeconomic pattern here...

Comment: @EnvisionAndDevelop, well, I didn't mean that strictly, I think we're operating under an open-source, free-sharing, collaborative effort, the points are not for profit, hell, I wish I could trade them for a nice Risotto with Salmon at a good restaurant ;) Anyway, what pattern are you detecting?

Comment: @brasofilo _"each one of us is a mini-Federal Reserve"_ we all have the privilege of printing paper money. As so, the total reputation probably grows much more faster than the "overall expertise of the community", this has for corollary than the reputation's "value" lowers inevitably over the time.

Answer (score 5):

Just to address a minor side question of "If nobody has 2000 rep to approve suggested edits, how can you gain rep via suggested edits?":

These days, SE community team (who have full moderator power and show up with moderator diamonds instead of much-cooler tridents they used to have) hang out at new SE sites, and do moderator duty until moderators Pro Tempore are chosen. As part of moderator duty, they approve edit suggestions (which they can do with any rep, having basically unlimited power on the site).